# Regex : Only start Mozilla and not 'bot' in words

Tags: regex, robots.txt

ex. UserAgent (accepted) : `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36`

I woud like create regex who accepted only UserAgent who start by `Mozilla` but not contain the `bot` word

ex. not accepted :

`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)`

Thanks

Comment: Who reads robots.txt?

Comment: my langague it's PCRE (php) and it will read by package with condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, look ahead are a good way to create condition one the string inside one regex.

```
^(?!.*bot)Mozilla.*$
```

- `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead. It will fail the whole regex if what's inside matches, so here if there is `bot` somewhere in your string (even inside a word)
- `^$` are anchors matching the beginning and the end of your string

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/iN4zA7

Answer (score 0):

Use negative look aheads for this challenge:
(?!bot)

```
^Mozilla((?!bot).)*$
```

Comment: `((?!bot).)*` works, but the regex engine will perform a negative lookahead check on each character of the string, which isn't great perform wise. You might want to replace it with something like `(?!.*bot).*`, to check it only once